# How to hide Permission tab at Admin System Dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, permissions, system.xml, system-config

I want to remove `Permission` Tab at the admin->system dropdown programmatically. Not its functionality, just want to hide the select option at admin.

How to do it?.

Comment: What about creating a new admin user with a new admin role that is not allowed to access it ? It will do it.

Comment: yeah I know, But my client told me to hide it even from the administrator

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution,

Added following code at `adminhtml.xml`,hides the Permission tab at the admin System

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <system>
            <children>
            <!-- Hide Permission -->
                <acl>
                    <depends>
                        <module>HideMe</module>
                    </depends>
                </acl>
            </children>
        </system>
    </menu>
</config>
```